# Index out of range exception while inserting elements into a list

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist

I keep getting the following error:
"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection", while executing the following code:

```
 try
        {
            string connectionstring = "server=localhost;user id=root;database=itemdb;password=root";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring);
            conn.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT item.item_name,location.city,time.month,SUM(unit_sales) FROM sales_fact,time,item,location WHERE(sales_fact.item_key = item.item_key AND sales_fact.location_key = location.location_key AND sales_fact.time_key = time.time_key) GROUP BY item.item_name", conn);
            MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int c = 0;
            List<Cube1> cubelist = new List<Cube1>();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                //i++;
                cubelist[c].itemname = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                cubelist[c].city = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                cubelist[c].month = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
                cubelist[c].totalsales = (int)dr.GetValue(3);
                MessageBox.Show(cubelist[0].totalsales.ToString());
                c++;
            }
            dr.Close();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(connectionstring, conn);
            DataSet dt = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You should be doing cubelist.Add().

Comment: Min mod: change `//i++;` to `cubelist.Add(new Cube1());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your list is empty, but you are trying to access it's elements.You should use `List<T>.Add` method first. In your code:

```
new List<Cube1>(100);
```

`100` only specifies the `Capacity`, it isn't the size of your list.It is used to allocate an array with specified length to avoid re-allocation every time you add a new item to your list.

```
cubelist.Add(new Cube());
cubelist[c].itemname = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
cubelist[c].city = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
...
```

Comment: The Poster has changed its code now, but not the title :-)

Comment: @Steve yea you right but still the same exception remains. :) the indexer of `List<T>` throws exception, in order to get nullreference you should have at least a _null_ item :)

Answer (score 2):

You create a new (empty) `List<Cube1>` and then try to assign to properties of elements that don't exist because the list is empty. Instead of using `cubelist[c]`, you need to be doing `var cube = new Cube1()` to instantiate a new `Cube1`, then assigning the values to its properties, then adding that to the list using `cubelist.Add(cube)`.

```
List<Cube1> cubelist = new List<Cube1>();
while (dr.Read())
{
    // Create a new Cube1 instance
    var cube = new Cube1();

    // Set its properties
    cube.itemname = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
    cube.city = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
    cube.month = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
    cube.totalsales = (int)dr.GetValue(3);

    // Add it to the list
    cubelist.Add(cube);

    MessageBox.Show(cube.totalsales.ToString());
}
```

You don't need your `c` variable at all.